# Mapping Dictionary with entity based key using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following NHibernate HBM that works as expected, but it makes my code brittle as the classes may change and I want to do the mapping in FNH, but try as I might, I cannot seem to get it to work, especially how you get the index-many-to-many:

```
<map name="Permissions" table="PermissionsBySet" cascade="all">
  <key column="PermissionSet_id" />
  <index-many-to-many class="Picomole.ReadModel.Permission, Picomole.ReadModel" column="PermissionId" />
  <element column="PermissionType" type="Picomole.ReadModel.PermissionType, Picomole.ReadModel" not-null="true" />
</map>
```

Given the following classes:

```
public class PermissionSet : DomainObject
{
    public virtual PermissionSet Defaults { get; set; }

    public virtual IDictionary<Permission, PermissionType> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission : DomainObject
{
    public virtual string Controller { get; set; }

    public virtual string Action { get; set; }
}

public enum PermissionType
{
    None,
    Read,
    Write,
    Grant
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Firo for point me in the right direction.  The final answer for what I was attempting to do was:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions)
                .AsEntityMap("PermissionId", "PermissionLevel")
                .Element("PermissionLevel", x => x.Type<PermissionLevel>())
                .Table("PermissionsBySet");
```

And because of some issues I was having with a strange error about the session connection being closed, I had to add:

```
                .Fetch.Join()
                .Not.LazyLoad()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PermissionSetMap : ClassMap<PermissionSet>
{
    public PermissionSetMap()
    {
        HasManyToMany(ps => ps.Permissions)
            .AsEntityMap("permissions_id")
            .Element("PermissionType");
    }
}
```