# Fluent NHibernate mapping of Dictionary<Entity, int>

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dictionary, fluent-nhibernate

In my domain I have a `Transport` which can access `Endpoints` at certain positions, as such I have the following:

```
public class Transport
{
    public IDictionary<Endpoint, int> AccessPointPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to map the `AccessPointPosition` through a combination of `HasMany` and `AsMap`, but I haven't succeeded in finding anything that passes the Fluent NHibernate configuration.

Am I overlooking something? Is this impossible? Is there any documentation on this subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mapping with fluent could be like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.AccessPointPosition)
   // these are most likely by convention
   // .Table("tbl_AccessPointPosition") 
   // .KeyColumn("Transport_id")
   // ...
   .AsEntityMap("Endpoint_id")
   .Element("integer_col", part => part.Type<int>());
```

Some other related questions:

- [Fluent nHibernate , IDictionary Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3925112/1679310)
- [Mapping Dictionary with entity based key using Fluent Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9667620/1679310)
- [Search for equivalent Fluent Nhibernate Mapping - Mapping Map as Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10191275/1679310)

Comment: You're a hero. Did figure it out yesterday (intellisense + googling) but you're exactly right.

Comment: Great if that helped. Enjoy NHibernate. it is amazing tool ;) not so easy to learn... but then ;)